# Solr in TomCat on Windows Server 2008 R2 - Solr doesn't start automatically

Tags: solr, tomcat7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have followed this guide to install Solr in TomCat running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

http://drupal.org/node/1359598

As described in step 6 of the guide I can run Solr from the command line using the following:

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=c:/solr/ -jar start.jar
```

As expected I can now see Solr at `http://localhost:8983/solr/`

If I reboot the server Solr does not start automatically. I have to run the start.jar file via the command line as shown above.

I have tried adding the following to the Java Options in the Configure TomCat UI.

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=c:\solr
```

This doesn't work. The only way I can run Solr is to use the command line. I'm sure that this is a simple problem to resolve but I can't work it out. Does anyone have any idea what I've configured incorrectly?

My technology stack is:

- JRE 7
- TomCat 7.0
- Solr 3.6.0
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default servlet container in solr is jetty, not tomcat.  So when you are running java -jar start.jar you are starting jetty.

Please refer to the following doc on running [solr with tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat) .

Once you have done this, to start tomcat as a service that automatically restarts follow this doc http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: this article also shows how you can do it with picture.. nice detailed one... http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/installing-apache-solr/